# Flash AS3 Multi touch event handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

I have 3 separate movie clips in a frame, each clip can be moved around the stage using a simple touch and drag event, which is shown below, incase it has some relevance. I want to drag each of the three clips onto a fourth clip and when all 3 are contained within the fourth clip I want an event triggered that changes the current frame. What is the easiest way of doing this in AS3 ? Any examples would be great as I am a complete beginner. Thanks

```
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

    Gem1_MC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fl_TouchBeginHandler_2);
    Gem1_MC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, fl_TouchEndHandler_2);

    var fl_DragBounds_2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

    function fl_TouchBeginHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void

{



 event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds_2);
    }

    function fl_TouchEndHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future you'd want to implement a solution where your drag and drop functionality is abstracted into a class but to work with what you've got, here's a basic solution:

Keep track of when the three `MovieClips` are considered "contained within" the fourth clip

```
var contained:Array = new Array(false, false, false);
```

In the event of an object finishing it's drag, check to see if it's contained in `mc1`.  At the end of these checks, find out if they're all true:

```
function fl_TouchEndHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void {
    // Drag & drop stuff...
    contained[2] = Gem2_MC.hitTestObject(Gem4_MC)); // where Gem4_MC is your 4th movie clip.

    if (contained.indexOf(false) == -1) { // This returns -1 if it can't find false
        gotoAndStop(frame_number_you_want);
    }
}
```

As a side note, `hitTestObject()` uses a simple "bounding box" to dectect "collision".  This means it may register a hit as true even when two movie clips don't look like they're actually touching.  Pixel perfect collision detection in Flash is possible but more complicated and worth its own post.  [A simple example of pixel perfect collision in AS3 can be found here](http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/05/pixel-perfect-collision-detection/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already have complete Multi touch drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Thanks very much but I'm having trouble implementing this successfully, I receive an error, Access of undefined property i and Access of undefined property Gem4. Any suggestions ?

Comment: My apologies, I changed the `i` to a `2` because, from the looks of your sample code, you have an `fl_TouchEndHandler` for each of the movie clips.  Also, I was just guessing that your 4th Movie clip was named `Gem4_MC`.  This variable should be whatever you named your 4th movie clip.

Comment: Unfortunately it's spitting out another error. Shown below. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: contained[2] = Gem2_MC.hitTestObject(Gem4_MC)); is receiving an error now -  Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Alright, if this is coming from the `hitTestObject` function that it means Gem4_MC is a class, not an instance of a class.  When you click on your 4th movie clip on the stage, look at the [properties inspector](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/property-inspector.png) and make sure the name in the box matches the name you type in `hitTestObject` and that the drop down has `Movie Clip` selected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I resolved that issue, instance was named incorrectly. Testing this solution now !

Comment: You are absolutely fantastic ! I'm sorry I was a little slow at times but thanks so much for your patience. Solution works perfectly !